# Recursive method call in MouseEvent flow issue

Tags: java, swing, recursion, mouseevent, jtextarea

I hope this is not too specific, but I am having trouble understanding the logical flow of my recursive method.

**The goal:** create a book type gui that will display texts, keeping line breaks, using word wrap and page wrap between 2 JTextAreas.  I did not want to do this via scroll panes and want to have a book effect with buttons for flipping pages left/right.

**The [pseudo]code:** pull and manipulate the text into (monospace fitted) lines, put X lines into a page.  Enable left/right buttons if previous/next pages exist.  Show x page on left, x+1 page on right.  use of (leftPageCursor) to hold current left page.

In order to do this, my idea was to have a recursive display method that 'shows/hides' left/right buttons, puts text onto JTextAreas, and adds button listener code.  It works on the first click right, but then gets really messy and (leftPageCursor) goes out of control.  I created the following SSCCEE for anyone to see what I mean/logic.

I would really appreciate any help on this, I'm out of ideas. I tried many things the last of which (e.consume) with no luck.

**SSCCEE:** (please excuse the length - I wanted it to run while keeping it nicely commented)

```
public class ReadJIntLauncher extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static JTextArea textAreaLeft, textAreaRight;
    static JButton btnPageLeft, btnPageRight;
    static int leftPageCursor = 0, readMessageId = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ReadJIntLauncher frame = new ReadJIntLauncher();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    HashMap<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_0", "PAGE 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_1", "incididunt ut labore etdolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_2", "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_3", "irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esseees");

                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_4", "PAGE 2: cillum dolore deserunt anim id est laborum anim id est laborum incididunt ut");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_5", "labore incididunt ut labore etdolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_6", "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_7", "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.");

                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_8", "PAGE 3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_9", "incididunt ut labore etdolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_10", "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_11", "irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esseees");

                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_12", "PAGE 4: cillum dolore deserunt anim id est laborum anim id est laborum incididunt ut");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_13", "labore incididunt ut labore etdolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_14", "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_15", "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.");

                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_16", "PAGE 5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_17", "incididunt ut labore etdolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud");
                    messages.put("read_paragraph_1_18", "exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.");

                    final HashMap<Integer, String> readLines = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                    int lineCount = 0;
                    String entireText = "";

                    //grab all of the messages into entireText
                    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
                        if (messages.containsKey("read_paragraph_" + readMessageId + "_" + i)){
                            String read = messages.get("read_paragraph_" + readMessageId + "_" + i);
                            entireText += read + " |";
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //split the entire text by spaces
                    String[] readSplitSpaces = entireText.split("\\s");

                    //put words into readLines
                    String singleLine = "";
                    for (String s : readSplitSpaces){
                        s = s + " ";
                        int wordLength = s.length();
                        if (s.contains("|")){
                            String[] sSplitStrings = s.split("\\|");
                            singleLine += sSplitStrings[0];
                            readLines.put(lineCount, singleLine);
                            lineCount++;
                            singleLine = sSplitStrings[1];
                        } else {
                            if ((singleLine.length() + wordLength) <= 26){
                                singleLine += s;
                            } else {
                                readLines.put(lineCount, singleLine);
                                lineCount++;
                                singleLine = s;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //print out readLines
                    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
                        if (readLines.containsKey(i)){
                            System.out.println("[" + i + "] : " + readLines.get(i));
                        } else { break; }
                    }

                    //put readLines into readPages
                    final HashMap<Integer, String> readPages = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                    int totalPageCount = lineCount / 15;
                    if (lineCount % 15 != 0){ //round up for partial pages
                        totalPageCount++;
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalPageCount; i++){
                        String tmpPage = "";
                        for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++){
                            if (readLines.containsKey(k + (i * 15))){
                                tmpPage += readLines.get(k + (i * 15)) + "\r\n";
                            }
                        }
                        readPages.put(i, tmpPage); //i is pageCount
                    }

                    //print out readPages
                    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
                        if (readPages.containsKey(i)){
                            System.out.println("[" + i + "] : " + readPages.get(i));
                        } else { break; }
                    }   

                    displayReadPages(readPages);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ReadJIntLauncher() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 600, 430);
        JPanel jint = new JPanel();

        jint.setBounds(100, 100, 534, 428);
        jint.setLayout(null);

        textAreaLeft = new JTextArea();
        textAreaLeft.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textAreaLeft.setBounds(25, 37, 213, 297);
        jint.add(textAreaLeft);

        textAreaRight = new JTextArea();
        textAreaRight.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        textAreaRight.setBounds(261, 37, 213, 297);
        jint.add(textAreaRight);

        btnPageLeft = new JButton("left");
        btnPageLeft.setBounds(10, 345, 89, 23);
        jint.add(btnPageLeft);

        btnPageRight = new JButton("right");
        btnPageRight.setBounds(385, 345, 89, 23);
        jint.add(btnPageRight);

        getContentPane().add(jint);
    }

    public static void displayReadPages(final HashMap<Integer, String> readConvo){
        System.out.println("\nonLeftPage: " + leftPageCursor);
        //enable buttons if necessary
        if (leftPageCursor != 0){
            btnPageLeft.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            btnPageLeft.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (readConvo.containsKey(leftPageCursor + 2)){
            btnPageRight.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            btnPageRight.setEnabled(false);
        }

        //set left and right page(possibly)
        textAreaLeft.setText(readConvo.get(leftPageCursor));            System.out.println("  left page: " + leftPageCursor);
        if (readConvo.containsKey(leftPageCursor + 1)) {
            textAreaRight.setText(readConvo.get(leftPageCursor + 1));   System.out.println("  right page: " + (leftPageCursor + 1));
        } else {
            textAreaRight.setText("");
        }

        btnPageLeft.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                    leftPageCursor -= 2;
                    displayReadPages(readConvo);
                }
            }
        });

        btnPageRight.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                    leftPageCursor += 2;
                    displayReadPages(readConvo);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the answer and want to leave this here in case anyone stumbles across this and wants to learn from my mistake.  I moved the .addMouseListener code into the constructor and it fixes the problem.  I guess it was registering each click another Listener rather than 'overwriting' so to speak.

The only issue I am having now is I am still able to click the 'disabled' buttons.

And here is the solution to that...

source: [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/333683/GUI/java/Disabled-button-clickable)

> The ActionListener is a higher level semantic event, and as such does
>   the right thing when your button is disabled, ie, it can't be
>   triggered. The MouseListener is a lower event. It's also working as
>   designed. Just because you have disabled the button doesn't prevent
>   people from trying to click on it, and the MouseListener is just
>   obediently informing you that a click has occured. The fact that it's
>   disabled is part of the state of the button, but doesn't affect the
>   event the MouseListener is trapping.